# Gradle dependencies update in all repositories

Tags: gradle, gitlab, build.gradle, dependency-management

I have the following issue to think about. There are several Gitlab repositories:

```
+--- lib1 repo -> published to private artifactory
+--- lib2 repo -> published to private artifactory
+--- service1 repo -> uses lib1 in gradle dependencies
+--- service2 repo -> uses lib2 in gradle dependencies
+--- service3 repo -> uses lib1 and lib2 in gradle dependencies
```

I need to find a way to upgrade all dependant serices when new version one of the libs released.
The option with `my:cool:lib1:+` is not suitable because there are some projects where libs should not be updated automatically.

Comment: What's the concrete problem in changing the version number in the gradle build files?

Comment: This is annoying to change version by hand in all repos. Moreover, I can forget to do it.

Comment: Then automate it with a script.

Comment: I wondering is there any general way to do it.

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: I do not understand why the `+` option is not suitable, as it is used in the consuming project. In general, project dependencies should not be updated automatically. You could use a bot that creates pull-requests for version updates.